# Extending a Laravel Class and modifying a function [Laravel, October CMS]

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, octobercms

I am using October CMS that is built upon Laravel for my Web App. I want to build a robust search for my Web App, and I've helped myself with the Site Search Plugin (https://octobercms.com/plugin/offline-sitesearch). However, I would like to extend this plugin, so any modifications to the plugin's code, won't be overriden when I update the core plugin itself.

Right now the search plugin is able to only process one input with the name of 'q'.

```
 class SearchResults extends ComponentBase
 {
   protected function prepareVars()
   {
    $this->setVar('pageNumber', Request::get('page', 1));
    $this->setVar('query', Request::get('q', '')); // This is where it gets the form input
    $this->setVar('noResultsMessage');
    $this->setVar('visitPageMessage');
    $this->setVar('showProviderBadge');
    $this->setVar('resultsPerPage');
    }
  }
```

This is problematic, because when I want to compare the `$query` variable with the database, I can only compare the whole search string for example `search?q=Query1`. However I want to make a search query array so I can compare different values with different columns in the DB. for example `search?q=Query1&y=Query2&z=Query3`.

What I want to do is extend the `protected function prepareVars()` like this:

```
protected function prepareVars()
{ 
  $this->setVar('query', Request::get('q', '')); 
  $this->setVar('query1', Request::get('y', '')); 
  $this->setVar('query2', Request::get('z', '')); 
}
```

Maybe even make the initial `$query` var into an associative array but I am not sure if the Symfony setVar method allows this (http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_1/sfcomponent)

I hope I have worded my question good enough, I can provide additional information if needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I know there's supposed to be a question in there somewhere, but I just don't see it.